# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException apenas no Glassfis 4

Tags: java, glassfish

Fiz uma rotina para pagamentos online na Cielo, JSF , os testes que fiz com Tomcat 9, com Windows 10 rodaram 100%, porem quando coloquei em produção no Glassfish 4, o sistema ao redirecionar para a pagina da Cielo vem com esse erro.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
    PKIX path building failed:
      sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
        unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

Acredito que não seja o código e sim alguma configuração de certificado do SO(Open Suse) ou Glassfish.

Comment: você colocou o certificado ssl no servidor?

Comment: Não, o sistema não tem certificado SSl. Ou você fala do SSl do site que vou acessar?

Comment: Esse erro que você está recebendo, é que essa sua biblioteca não encontrou o certificação no seu servidor. muito provavelmente o diretório que está na sua maquina de desenvolvimento é diferente do servidor, ou senão nem existe o arquivo no ser servidor ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, eu coloquei a aplicação para ignorar o SSL, chamando essa função antes do POST.

```
Uteis.ignorarSSL();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);

public static void ignorarSSL() throws Exception{
    //Cria um gerenciador de confiança que não valide cadeias de certificados
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){return null;}
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
    }};

    //Instala o gerenciador de confiança
    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que a VM que seu processo/servidor/aplicação Java roda se conecte com QUALQUER host https, o certificado daquele host precisa estar presente na keystore da mesma. [Como você citou glassfish, estou colocando um link com o passo a passo](https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-glassfish/).

Apenas reforçando, este não é problema de SO, isso é um passo já conhecido e deverá sempre ser feito em qualquer servidor (apena varia o passo a passo).

Comment: certo, vou tentar, mas com Tomcat não foi necessário.

Comment: ainda continua com erro, mesmo adicionando o certificado no cacerts.